# Creating .NET COM object from C++ application

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, com, c++builder

Here are the facts:

1) I have a .NET application which contains a class which has an exposed COM interface.

2) I have several C++ applications which instantiate an instance of this .NET COM class.

3) All C++ applications can successfully create the COM object on my dev PC.

4) On every other PC, one of my C++ applications fails to create the COM object failing with error: "No such interface supported". The remaining C++ applications don't fail.

Questions:

A) How can the interface be supported on my Dev PC and not others for one particular C++ app? The executable files are exactly the same on all machines.

B) How can all my C++ applications successfully instantiate the COM object, but one can't. It is literally the same code reused in each application.

C) How can I fix this? Is there some config setting I can tweak?

Thanks.

Comment: Be sure to register the server with Regasm.exe's /tlb option and try again.

Comment: Already done that. I have four C++ applications that CAN create the .NET COM object (signifying regasm was successful) and only one that can't. Same assemblies, same code. On my dev PC there are no problems at all. Could it be a memory management issue?

Comment: So far this has only been tested on x86 machines, both WinXP and Win7. My Dev PC is WinXP x86.

Comment: have you checked the registry to see if the registration of the COM object worked? (hint: search for GUID)

Comment: Thanks for the ideas everyone. In the end I went right back to square one, rebuilt each assembly one at a time and the problem went away. I think I was thrown off the scent by the conflicting symptoms. Thanks again.